# Endpoints aren't eligible in amazon pinpoint campaign creation

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, aws-amplify

When I try to create a campaign in amazon pinpoint no eligible endpoints show up in the segment creation section. Even though I have a device successfully receiving push notifications from the test messaging section.

I have implemented iOS push notifications for my react-native app exactly as shown in the documentation (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/push-notifications). Everything works without any errors on the frontend and the backend. When I run the code:

```
PushNotification.onRegister((token) => console.log(token));
```

I successfully receive the app token. 
I can even receive push notifications from the test messaging section by using the token generated from the onRegister function.

However when I try to create a campaign in amazon pinpoint. I cannot get farther than the create segment section because despite there being 6 total endpoints, there are 0 eligible endpoints. Why are my endpoints ineligible? 
I have tested on a device. I have tested in a simulator. I tried changing the  IAM access of my auth and un auth roles to

"mobiletargeting:*"

so that they have full access to pinpoint.

What am I missing? Why are my endpoints ineligible?

In all of the tutorials that I have gone through. The segment automatically recognizes that the test device is eligible. Why is this not working for my project?

Comment: Have you ever found the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

I found using `Analytics.updateEndpoint()` in Amplify that I need to set `optOut: 'NONE'` and then my endpoint was eligible to create a campaign

See "Update Endpoint" section from here https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/analytics